# An application of the Optional Sampling Theorem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

let $S(k), k\geq 0$ a discrete random process. Suppose $S(N)$ is with probability one either 100 or 0 and that $S(0)=50$. Suppose further there is at least a sixty percent probability that the price will at some point dip below 40 and then subsequently rise above 60 before time $N$. 
How do you prove that $S(k)$ cannot be a martingale?

By advance, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The upper bound on the probability of falling to $40$ and then increasing to $60$ seems to be $\frac{100-50}{100-40}\times \frac{40-0}{60-0} = \frac59 < 60 \%$ taking into account the end points of $0$ and $100$ and the martingale

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $X_{t}$ is a martingale and define

$\tau$ = $\inf_{n \le N} \{ n: X_{n} \le 40 \}$,

$\sigma$ = $\inf_{\tau \le n \le N} \{ n: X_{n} \ge 60 \}$,
where we assume that $\inf \emptyset = + \infty$.

Since $0 \le \tau \wedge N \le \sigma \wedge N \le N$,  from Doob's Theorem:

$\mathbb{E}(X_{0})=\mathbb{E}(X_{\tau \wedge N})=\mathbb{E}(X_{\sigma \wedge N})$.

Because

$50  = \mathbb{E}(X_{0}) =\mathbb{E}(X_{\tau \wedge N}) = \mathbb{E}(X_{\tau} \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \le N\}}+ X_{N} \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau > N\}}) = \mathbb{E}(X_{\tau} \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \le N\}}) + \mathbb{E}(X_{N} \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau > N\}}) = 40 \cdot \mathbb{P}(\tau \le N) + \mathbb{E}(X_{N} \mathbb{1}_{ \{\tau > N \}}) \le 40 \cdot \mathbb{P}(\tau \le N) + 100 \cdot \mathbb{P}(\tau > N )  = 100 - 60\cdot \mathbb{P}(\tau \le N )$

so we obtain inequality

$\mathbb{P}(\tau \le N ) \le \frac{5}{6} $ .

Then

$50 = \mathbb{E}(X_{0})=\mathbb{E}(X_{\sigma \wedge N})= \mathbb{E}(X_{\sigma} \mathbb{1}_{\{\sigma \le N\}}+ X_{N} \mathbb{1}_{\{\sigma > N\}}) = 60 \cdot \mathbb{P}(\sigma \le N) + \mathbb{E}(X_{N}\mathbb{1}_{ \{\sigma \ge \tau > N \}} + X_{N}\mathbb{1}_{ \{\sigma \ge N \ge \tau \}}) \ge 60 \cdot \mathbb{P}(\sigma \le N) + 100 \cdot \mathbb{P}(\tau > N) + 0$

so we obtain

$100 \cdot \mathbb{P}(\tau \le N) \ge 60 \cdot \mathbb{P}(\sigma \le N) +50$,

using first obtained inequality

$100 \cdot \frac{5}{6} \ge 60 \cdot\mathbb{P}(\sigma \le N) +50$

and finally

$\mathbb{P}(\sigma \le N) \le \frac{5}{9}$